# Why is there no static method in the Arrays class to swap elements of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I know it is simple and understandable enough, but why it has not been added?

```
public static void swap(Object[] array, int i, int j) {
     Object temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[j];
     array[j] = temp;
}
```

Would be much simpler just to call `Arrays.swap(arr, i, j)` than to reimplement it each time from scratch.

Comment: Unless one of the API architects from Java comes along, we can only guess as to the reasons. Which makes this primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Did you really vote to close your own question?

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes.

Comment: @lealceldeiro, sure.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I wasn't aware you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly because we (in the sense of all people who use Java) don't really need or want it.

Bear in mind that every method added to the API is a long-term maintenance commitment; if it doesn't carry its own weight, it won't be done. It is easy to overestimate the value of code we write to others (who, myself included, has never thought "this code will be so useful to other people!"); but you would need to actually demonstrate an unmet need in the broader Java community for it to be worth adopting.

Adding just a method for swapping object arrays is arbitrary: you should really add overloads for all 8 primitive types too, for completeness, and consistency with the other methods; but would that really be worthwhile?

Either implement it yourself, or use `Arrays.asList` to wrap the array:

```
Collections.swap(Arrays.asList(array), i, j);
```

---

On an implementation note, it would not need to be generic.

```
public static void swap(Object[] array, int i, int j) {
     Object temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[j];
     array[j] = temp;
}
```

This would work, because of the variance of arrays.

Comment: Somehow it has been implemented for collections and not for arrays. I bet arrays were first and it would be more natural to have it there. Every time I need to write something simple (without any external dependencies and in a single file) I will have to write this method yet again just for compilation. Is not there an object overhead in the swap method call in Collections? I bet there is.

Comment: Actually, we do need it and want it and even it is implemented in JDK itself, but not exposed for some reason. Look at source of Collections - the version for arrays is implemented just below the swap for lists (temurin-17).

Comment: @pwojnowski the maintainers of the API don't want you to rely on the existence of that method, so they haven't made it part of the API. Moreover, they have only defined 1 of the 9 necessary overloads.